# General summation formula for...

Tags: summation, summation-method

I'm looking for a general summation formula for $\left((1-\lambda)\lambda^0+(1-\lambda)\lambda^1\right)R^{(2)} + \left((1-\lambda)\lambda^2+(1-\lambda)\lambda^3\right)R^{(4)} + \left((1-\lambda)\lambda^4+(1-\lambda)\lambda^5\right)R^{(6)} + \ldots$

Comment: What is $R^{(n)}$ ? Why do you keep all these $(1-\lambda)$ factors ?

Comment: $R^n$ ignore the parenthesis.

Comment: to ensure that the weights sum to 1.

Comment: They sum to $1+\lambda$, not to $1$. but the question was why don't you leave them in evidence.

Comment: no they really sum to 1.

Comment: use excel and see yourself. but $\lambda < 1$

Comment: @Yves Daoust You are doing it in the wrong way, let say for $\lambda=0.9$ and $R=1$. $\left((1-0.9)*0.9^0 + (1-0.9)*0.9^1 + (1-0.9)*0.9^2 + \ldots\right)=1$

Comment: You are right, sorry. There is a closed formula for the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

$$\sum _{i=0}^{\infty} (1-\lambda)({\lambda}^{2i}+{\lambda}^{2i+1})R^{(2i+2)}$$

As pointed out in the comments, you could factor the $(1-\lambda)$ term out of the sum as:

$$(1-\lambda)\sum _{i=0}^{\infty} ({\lambda}^{2i}+{\lambda}^{2i+1})R^{(2i+2)}$$

Comment: and what if $\left((1-\lambda)\lambda^0+(1-\lambda)\lambda^1+(1-\lambda)\lambda^2)\right)R^{(3)} + \left((1-\lambda)\lambda^3+(1-\lambda)\lambda^4+(1-\lambda)\lambda^5\right)R^{(6)} + \left((1-\lambda)\lambda^6+(1-\lambda)\lambda^7+(1-\lambda)\lambda^8\right)R^{(9)} + \ldots$ Is there how get a general formula. @GaussTheBauss

Comment: Is there another way without adding more terms to the summation?

Comment: @Davi $(1-\lambda)\sum _{i=0}^{\infty} ({\lambda}^{3i}+{\lambda}^{3i+1}+{\lambda}^{3i+2})R^{(3i+3)}$

Comment: no, I'm sorry. The number is 9.

Comment: Yes thanks. But the right would be $\sum_{i=0}^\infty(1-\lambda^{3i})\lambda^{3i}R^{3i+3}$.

Comment: Yes there is a cancellation, the where the sum is 1. But there is something about R that I don't tell you, I'm sorry. R is another summation and the power is the number of sum.

Answer (score 1):

This sum can be written

$$(1-\lambda^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda^{2k}R^{(2k+2)}.$$

If $R^{(n)}$ is to be understood as $R^n$, this geometric series converges to

$$\frac{(1-\lambda^2)R^2}{1-\lambda^2R^2}$$ when $|\lambda R|<1$.

Comment: Shocking downvote.

Comment: and what if $\left((1-\lambda)\lambda^0+(1-\lambda)\lambda^1+(1-\lambda)\lambda^2)\right)R^{(3)} + \left((1-\lambda)\lambda^3+(1-\lambda)\lambda^4+(1-\lambda)\lambda^5\right)R^{(4)} + \left((1-\lambda)\lambda^6+(1-\lambda)\lambda^7+(1-\lambda)\lambda^8\right)R^{(6)} + \ldots$ Is there how get a general formula. @Yves Daoust

Comment: @davi: first fix the exponents of $R$.

Comment: @davi: $(1-\lambda^3)R^3/(1-\lambda^3R^3)$.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss Let's remove those comments then.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss: done. :)